# NodeJS generate PDF with clickable button

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I'd like to use nodejs module to generate pdf invoices with clickable link for payment. But it looks like none of the existing solution can generate a clickable link in PDF. Is this correct?

I learned that the click event is a problem from [this github issue](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/issues/261). 
Below is the code I use to generate pdf with no issue, but can you get a clickable link on pdf?

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' }
});
```

So, if I want to generate pdf with clickable links with Nodejs. What module I should use, or how to implement this in lower level e.g. using PhantomJS?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you [pdfkit](http://pdfkit.org/). Its pretty simple and easy to use. Below is an example from the official docs.

```
PDFDocument = require 'pdfkit'

# Create a document
doc = new PDFDocument
doc.addPage()
   .fillColor("blue")
   .text('Here is a link!', 100, 100)
   .underline(100, 100, 160, 27, color: "#0000FF")
   .link(100, 100, 160, 27, 'http://google.com/')
```

Comment: I've haven't generated pdf before, but I feel like using html and css is easier to control the result pdf style than using function command. Is my feeling wrong? Is using function command a standard practice for nodejs pdf generation?

Comment: well it would be very easy for you to style and control the structure in html and css but if your use case belongs to server side then i would suggest pdfkit is better .

Comment: I just browse through the doc of pdfkit. There is no command for generating table?

Comment: sorry but i did not consider that as important because you did not ask for it in the question.